# unresolved external symbol error in Visual Studio 2010 c++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, kinect, openni, point-cloud-library

I was writing a project with kinect using Point Cloud and openni based on normalization inside Visual studio 10 c++. But i am getting a huge list of error named unresolved external symbol. I am giving my source code and few error list below. Need help thanks in advance.

Source Code:

```
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Object for storing the point cloud.
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    // Object for storing the normals.
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normals(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);

    // Read a PCD file from disk.
    if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ>(argv[1], *cloud) != 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // Object for normal estimation.
    pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> normalEstimation;
    normalEstimation.setInputCloud(cloud);
    // For every point, use all neighbors in a radius of 3cm.
    normalEstimation.setRadiusSearch(0.03);
    // A kd-tree is a data structure that makes searches efficient. More about it later.
    // The normal estimation object will use it to find nearest neighbors.
    pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr kdtree(new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    normalEstimation.setSearchMethod(kdtree);

    // Calculate the normals.
    normalEstimation.compute(*normals);

    // Visualize them.
    boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("Normals"));
    viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(cloud, "cloud");
    // Display one normal out of 20, as a line of length 3cm.
    viewer->addPointCloudNormals<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal>(cloud, normals, 20, 0.03, "normals");
    while (!viewer->wasStopped())
    {
        viewer->spinOnce(100);
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::microseconds(100000));
    }
}
```

Error List:

```
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall vtkPolyData::SetLines(class vtkCellArray *)" (?SetLines@vtkPolyData@@QAEXPAVvtkCellArray@@@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addPointCloudNormals<struct pcl::PointXYZ,struct pcl::Normal>(class boost::shared_ptr<class pcl::PointCloud<struct pcl::PointXYZ> const > const&,class boost::shared_ptr<class pcl::PointCloud<struct pcl::Normal> const > const &,int,double,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (??$addPointCloudNormals@UPointXYZ@pcl@@UNormal@2@@PCLVisualizer@visualization@pcl@@QAE_NABV?$shared_ptr@$$CBV?$PointCloud@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@pcl@@@boost@@ABV?$shared_ptr@$$CBV?$PointCloud@UNormal@pcl@@@pcl@@@4@HNABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall vtkDataArrayTemplate<int>::InsertNextValue(int)" (?InsertNextValue@?$vtkDataArrayTemplate@H@@QAEHH@Z) referenced in function "public: int __thiscall vtkIdTypeArray::InsertNextValue(int)" (?InsertNextValue@vtkIdTypeArray@@QAEHH@Z)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall vtkDataArrayTemplate<int>::InsertValue(int,int)" (?InsertValue@?$vtkDataArrayTemplate@H@@QAEXHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall vtkIdTypeArray::InsertValue(int,int)" (?InsertValue@vtkIdTypeArray@@QAEXHH@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkHardwareSelector.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::~vtkSmartPointerBase(void)" (??1vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkStandardPolyDataPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::~vtkSmartPointerBase(void)" (??1vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@XZ)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::~vtkSmartPointerBase(void)" (??1vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointer<class vtkLODActor>::~vtkSmartPointer<class vtkLODActor>(void)" (??1?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkLODActor@@@@QAE@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkProperty.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::~vtkSmartPointerBase(void)" (??1vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkOpenGLGlyph3DMapper.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::~vtkSmartPointerBase(void)" (??1vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkScalarsToColorsPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::~vtkSmartPointerBase(void)" (??1vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@XZ)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall vtkDataArrayTemplate<float>::SetArray(float *,int,int,int)" (?SetArray@?$vtkDataArrayTemplate@M@@QAEXPAMHHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall vtkDataArrayTemplate<float>::SetArray(float *,int,int)" (?SetArray@?$vtkDataArrayTemplate@M@@QAEXPAMHH@Z)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkSmartPointerBase & __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::operator=(class vtkSmartPointerBase const &)" (??4vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) referenced in function "public: class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkLODActor> & __thiscall vtkSmartPointer<class vtkLODActor>::operator=(class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkLODActor> const &)" (??4?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkLODActor@@@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkProperty.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkSmartPointerBase & __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::operator=(class vtkSmartPointerBase const &)" (??4vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkOpenGLGlyph3DMapper.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkSmartPointerBase & __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::operator=(class vtkSmartPointerBase const &)" (??4vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkScalarsToColorsPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkSmartPointerBase & __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::operator=(class vtkSmartPointerBase const &)" (??4vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkPolyData * __cdecl vtkPolyData::New(void)" (?New@vtkPolyData@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkPolyData> __cdecl vtkSmartPointer<class vtkPolyData>::New(void)" (?New@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkPolyData@@@@SA?AV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkOpenGLGlyph3DMapper.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkPolyData * __cdecl vtkPolyData::New(void)" (?New@vtkPolyData@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkGlyph3DMapper.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkPolyData * __cdecl vtkPolyData::New(void)" (?New@vtkPolyData@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkPrimitivePainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkPolyData * __cdecl vtkPolyData::New(void)" (?New@vtkPolyData@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkCellArray * __cdecl vtkCellArray::New(void)" (?New@vtkCellArray@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkCellArray> __cdecl vtkSmartPointer<class vtkCellArray>::New(void)" (?New@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkCellArray@@@@SA?AV1@XZ)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkPoints * __cdecl vtkPoints::New(void)" (?New@vtkPoints@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkPoints> __cdecl vtkSmartPointer<class vtkPoints>::New(void)" (?New@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkPoints@@@@SA?AV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkOpenGLGlyph3DMapper.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkPoints * __cdecl vtkPoints::New(void)" (?New@vtkPoints@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkGlyph3DMapper.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkPoints * __cdecl vtkPoints::New(void)" (?New@vtkPoints@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkPicker.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkPoints * __cdecl vtkPoints::New(void)" (?New@vtkPoints@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkFloatArray * __cdecl vtkFloatArray::New(void)" (?New@vtkFloatArray@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkFloatArray> __cdecl vtkSmartPointer<class vtkFloatArray>::New(void)" (?New@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkFloatArray@@@@SA?AV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkMapper.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkFloatArray * __cdecl vtkFloatArray::New(void)" (?New@vtkFloatArray@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkScalarsToColorsPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkFloatArray * __cdecl vtkFloatArray::New(void)" (?New@vtkFloatArray@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::vtkSmartPointerBase(class vtkObjectBase *,class vtkSmartPointerBase::NoReference const &)" (??0vtkSmartPointerBase@@IAE@PAVvtkObjectBase@@ABVNoReference@0@@Z) referenced in function "protected: __thiscall vtkSmartPointer<class vtkLODActor>::vtkSmartPointer<class vtkLODActor>(class vtkLODActor *,classvtkSmartPointerBase::NoReference const &)" (??0?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkLODActor@@@@IAE@PAVvtkLODActor@@ABVNoReference@vtkSmartPointerBase@@@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkScalarsToColorsPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::vtkSmartPointerBase(class vtkObjectBase *,class vtkSmartPointerBase::NoReference const &)" (??0vtkSmartPointerBase@@IAE@PAVvtkObjectBase@@ABVNoReference@0@@Z)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::vtkSmartPointerBase(class vtkObjectBase *)" (??0vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@PAVvtkObjectBase@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointer<class vtkProp>::vtkSmartPointer<class vtkProp><class vtkLODActor>(class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkLODActor> const &)" (??$?0VvtkLODActor@@@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkProp@@@@QAE@ABV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkLODActor@@@@@Z)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall vtkDataArrayTemplate<unsigned char>::SetArray(unsigned char *,int,int,int)" (?SetArray@?$vtkDataArrayTemplate@E@@QAEXPAEHHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall vtkDataArrayTemplate<unsigned char>::SetArray(unsigned char *,int,int)" (?SetArray@?$vtkDataArrayTemplate@E@@QAEXPAEHH@Z)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkUnsignedCharArray * __cdecl vtkUnsignedCharArray::New(void)" (?New@vtkUnsignedCharArray@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkUnsignedCharArray> __cdecl vtkSmartPointer<class vtkUnsignedCharArray>::New(void)" (?New@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkUnsignedCharArray@@@@SA?AV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkHardwareSelector.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkSmartPointerBase & __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::operator=(class vtkObjectBase *)" (??4vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAEAAV0@PAVvtkObjectBase@@@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkStandardPolyDataPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkSmartPointerBase & __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::operator=(class vtkObjectBase *)" (??4vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAEAAV0@PAVvtkObjectBase@@@Z)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkSmartPointerBase & __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::operator=(class vtkObjectBase *)" (??4vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAEAAV0@PAVvtkObjectBase@@@Z) referenced in function "public: class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkDataArray> & __thiscall vtkSmartPointer<class vtkDataArray>::operator=<class vtkUnsignedCharArray>(class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkUnsignedCharArray> const &)" (??$?4VvtkUnsignedCharArray@@@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkDataArray@@@@QAEAAV0@ABV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkUnsignedCharArray@@@@@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkProperty.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkSmartPointerBase & __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::operator=(class vtkObjectBase *)" (??4vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAEAAV0@PAVvtkObjectBase@@@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkOpenGLGlyph3DMapper.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkSmartPointerBase & __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::operator=(class vtkObjectBase *)" (??4vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAEAAV0@PAVvtkObjectBase@@@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkScalarsToColorsPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkSmartPointerBase & __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::operator=(class vtkObjectBase *)" (??4vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAEAAV0@PAVvtkObjectBase@@@Z)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall vtkDataSetAttributes::SetScalars(class vtkDataArray *)" (?SetScalars@vtkDataSetAttributes@@QAEHPAVvtkDataArray@@@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::fromHandlersToScreen<struct pcl::PointXYZ>(class pcl::visualization::PointCloudGeometryHandler<struct pcl::PointXYZ> const &,class pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandler<struct pcl::PointXYZ> const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int,class Eigen::Matrix<float,4,1,0,4,1> const &,class Eigen::Quaternion<float,0> const &)" (??$fromHandlersToScreen@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@PCLVisualizer@visualization@pcl@@AAE_NABV?$PointCloudGeometryHandler@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@12@ABV?$PointCloudColorHandler@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@12@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@HABV?$Matrix@M$03$00$0A@$03$00@Eigen@@ABV?$Quaternion@M$0A@@8@@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkMapper.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall vtkDataSetAttributes::SetScalars(class vtkDataArray *)" (?SetScalars@vtkDataSetAttributes@@QAEHPAVvtkDataArray@@@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkScalarsToColorsPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall vtkDataSetAttributes::SetScalars(class vtkDataArray *)" (?SetScalars@vtkDataSetAttributes@@QAEHPAVvtkDataArray@@@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkHardwareSelector.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::vtkSmartPointerBase(void)" (??0vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkStandardPolyDataPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::vtkSmartPointerBase(void)" (??0vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@XZ)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::vtkSmartPointerBase(void)" (??0vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointer<class vtkLODActor>::vtkSmartPointer<class vtkLODActor>(void)" (??0?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkLODActor@@@@QAE@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkProperty.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::vtkSmartPointerBase(void)" (??0vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkOpenGLGlyph3DMapper.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::vtkSmartPointerBase(void)" (??0vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkScalarsToColorsPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::vtkSmartPointerBase(void)" (??0vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkLODProp3D.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkMatrix4x4 * __cdecl vtkMatrix4x4::New(void)" (?New@vtkMatrix4x4@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkMatrix4x4 * __cdecl vtkMatrix4x4::New(void)" (?New@vtkMatrix4x4@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkInteractorStyleJoystickActor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkMatrix4x4 * __cdecl vtkMatrix4x4::New(void)" (?New@vtkMatrix4x4@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkOpenGLLight.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkMatrix4x4 * __cdecl vtkMatrix4x4::New(void)" (?New@vtkMatrix4x4@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkOpenGLCamera.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkMatrix4x4 * __cdecl vtkMatrix4x4::New(void)" (?New@vtkMatrix4x4@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkRenderer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkMatrix4x4 * __cdecl vtkMatrix4x4::New(void)" (?New@vtkMatrix4x4@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkCamera.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkMatrix4x4 * __cdecl vtkMatrix4x4::New(void)" (?New@vtkMatrix4x4@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkMatrix4x4 * __cdecl vtkMatrix4x4::New(void)" (?New@vtkMatrix4x4@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkMatrix4x4> __cdecl vtkSmartPointer<class vtkMatrix4x4>::New(void)" (?New@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkMatrix4x4@@@@SA?AV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkLODActor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkMatrix4x4 * __cdecl vtkMatrix4x4::New(void)" (?New@vtkMatrix4x4@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkProp3D.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkMatrix4x4 * __cdecl vtkMatrix4x4::New(void)" (?New@vtkMatrix4x4@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkOpenGLClipPlanesPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vtkMatrix4x4 * __cdecl vtkMatrix4x4::New(void)" (?New@vtkMatrix4x4@@SAPAV1@XZ)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall vtkCellArray::SetCells(int,class vtkIdTypeArray *)" (?SetCells@vtkCellArray@@QAEXHPAVvtkIdTypeArray@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::convertPointCloudToVTKPolyData<struct pcl::PointXYZ>(class pcl::visualization::PointCloudGeometryHandler<struct pcl::PointXYZ> const &,class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkPolyData> &,class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkIdTypeArray> &)" (??$convertPointCloudToVTKPolyData@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@PCLVisualizer@visualization@pcl@@AAEXABV?$PointCloudGeometryHandler@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@12@AAV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkPolyData@@@@AAV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkIdTypeArray@@@@@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkPolygonsPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkCellArray * __thiscall vtkPolyData::GetVerts(void)" (?GetVerts@vtkPolyData@@QAEPAVvtkCellArray@@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkLinesPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkCellArray * __thiscall vtkPolyData::GetVerts(void)" (?GetVerts@vtkPolyData@@QAEPAVvtkCellArray@@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkPointsPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkCellArray * __thiscall vtkPolyData::GetVerts(void)" (?GetVerts@vtkPolyData@@QAEPAVvtkCellArray@@XZ)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkCellArray * __thiscall vtkPolyData::GetVerts(void)" (?GetVerts@vtkPolyData@@QAEPAVvtkCellArray@@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::convertPointCloudToVTKPolyData<struct pcl::PointXYZ>(class pcl::visualization::PointCloudGeometryHandler<struct pcl::PointXYZ> const &,class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkPolyData> &,class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkIdTypeArray> &)" (??$convertPointCloudToVTKPolyData@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@PCLVisualizer@visualization@pcl@@AAEXABV?$PointCloudGeometryHandler@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@12@AAV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkPolyData@@@@AAV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkIdTypeArray@@@@@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkHardwareSelectionPolyDataPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkCellArray * __thiscall vtkPolyData::GetVerts(void)" (?GetVerts@vtkPolyData@@QAEPAVvtkCellArray@@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkStandardPolyDataPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkCellArray * __thiscall vtkPolyData::GetVerts(void)" (?GetVerts@vtkPolyData@@QAEPAVvtkCellArray@@XZ)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkIdentColoredPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkCellArray * __thiscall vtkPolyData::GetVerts(void)" (?GetVerts@vtkPolyData@@QAEPAVvtkCellArray@@XZ)
1>Test3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall vtkPolyData::SetVerts(class vtkCellArray *)" (?SetVerts@vtkPolyData@@QAEXPAVvtkCellArray@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::convertPointCloudToVTKPolyData<struct pcl::PointXYZ>(class pcl::visualization::PointCloudGeometryHandler<struct pcl::PointXYZ> const &,class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkPolyData> &,class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkIdTypeArray> &)" (??$convertPointCloudToVTKPolyData@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@PCLVisualizer@visualization@pcl@@AAEXABV?$PointCloudGeometryHandler@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@12@AAV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkPolyData@@@@AAV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkIdTypeArray@@@@@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkTDxInteractorStyle.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall vtkTDxInteractorStyle::ProcessEvent(class vtkRenderer *,unsigned long,void *)" (?ProcessEvent@vtkTDxInteractorStyle@@UAEXPAVvtkRenderer@@KPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkTDxInteractorStyleSettings.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkVolume.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkTDxInteractorStyleCamera.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkCellPicker.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkVolumeProperty.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkInteractorStyleJoystickActor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkInteractorObserver.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkWorldPointPicker.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkShaderDeviceAdapter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkInteractorStyle.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkInteractorStyleJoystickCamera.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkProp3DCollection.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkAbstractVolumeMapper.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkLODProp3D.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkPrimitivePainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkGLSLShaderDeviceAdapter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkGLSLShader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkCuller.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkAbstractPropPicker.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkRendererCollection.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkInteractorStyleSwitch.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkPropPicker.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkObserverMediator.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkTStripsPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkPolygonsPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkLinesPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkPointsPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkAreaPicker.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkAbstractPicker.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkPicker.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkIdentColoredPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkFrustumCoverageCuller.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkCullerCollection.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkVolumeCollection.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkActorCollection.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkShader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkCompositePainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
1>vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkOpenGLHardwareSupport.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl vtkObject::operator delete(void *)" (??3vtkObject@@SAXPAX@Z)
```

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem ?

Answer (score -1):

Below links will give an insight about the error

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx

[How to solve the error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol - function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886397/how-to-solve-the-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-function)

1.Check you have latest libs that matches with calling headers.
2.Calling convention.
3.Including libs in linker for dll.

Comment: Can you please tell me which lib files i needed from where i can get them. thanks .

Answer (score -1):

Two things  you must check:

1) if compiling the debug version, the linked libs must have the "xxxxx**-gd**.lib" (-gd) suffix after the library, whereas when compiling the release version this must not be present. i.e. -lvtkCommon for release, -lvtkCommon-gd for debug.

2) did you add all the -lvtkXXXX files to your linker in the Makefile? Please share your makefile.

Adding the following to makefile worked for me.

*-lvtkFiltering -lvtkGraphics -lvtkCommon -lvtkViews -lvtkRendering -lvtkIO -lvtkmetaio -lvtkImaging  -lvtkalglib -lvtksys -lvtkHybrid -lvtkWidgets*