# Created an empty project in visual studio and it doesn't seem to open console anymore?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I was having errors with a project that I created using the console application template and decide to re-create the project with an empty template. This seems to have dealt with the "unresolved external symbol" error I was receiving but now the console won't open when I call cout for output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "pch.h"
#include "word.h"
#include "dictionary.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Dictionary dic;
    dic.loadDictionary();
    cout >> "Hey\n" >> endl;
    cout.flush();
}
```

There are two class files that are being used but as there are no error I don;t believe they are needed to be seen.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: The original project that was receiving errors were "LNK2019  unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Dictionary::loadDictionary(void)" (?loadDictionary@Dictionary@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main ConsoleApplicationASS"

Comment: Can you post the exact errors you get?

Comment: @P.W Well I just realised that it seems there is something major wrong with the project or Im not doing something right, because I'm not receiving any errors whatsoever, even if I intentionally mess up the syntax

Answer (score 1):

Use `<<` instead of `>>`. Also put `getch()` at the end for the console to wait for your input so that you can see the console output.

After edit on the question, you should [read about solving the LNK2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886397/how-to-solve-the-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-function/46673248).

Comment: No luck, when I rebuild it still doesn't appear with the console. However, Im unsure how I was not getting errors when using the wrong << with cout.

Comment: Try a sample hello world first to clear your doubts. https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/examples/print-sentence

Comment: The issue isn't that I can't write a program that can output to console, my issue is that I have the code that would typically output to a console that would open up when the project is built. But my project is simply not doing that even though it should.

Comment: Then to solve this issue one needs to have a look at the project. By just having a look at the code you pasted in your question we cannot figure out the bug. Please give us a mcve. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Well there are no errors, so should I post the full source code?

Comment: If the full source code is small enough you can post. But then it becomes like 'Can someone please debug this for me?'. So good to learn usage of debugging tools. MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is always recommended.

Comment: Yea I get that, should I just re-post the question and rephrase it as an issue with the project instead?

Comment: If it is project issue, the question might go broad or possibly drift away from the original question. Being a new contributor on the site, I recommend reading https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions. I recommend leaving this question as is. Ask a new question if you can come up with MCVE. Something similar to your doubt is https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296738/should-i-re-ask-a-question-if-i-have-edited-it-beyond-recognition.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is showing up, and closing before you see any output. Try <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>. That makes you input a keystroke at the end of execution similar to the `getch()` command.